# Quasar Vue: Set static width content on Grid Style

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm very new in dynamic web programming but I get a little problem with Quasar Grid Gutter.

I have string on array with different word and length, I want to show them in Button with grid style. So I use [Grid Gutter](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/gutter#Classes-%E2%80%9Cq-gutter-%7Bsize%7D%E2%80%9D) to build this. But I want the size of card is always static (etc width: 200), so add `style="width: 100px"`. But if width too small and text length too long, the height is getting weird. If add `height:50px` the width is not work. Here is a [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/si_cantik/pen/RwaZbRL?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2Flayout%2Fgrid%2Fgutter&__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=181fcdee36f4e257737147ecb36fd3842ec95049-1598838197-0-AbFZNpuT8LzGHaqHkpYirq0CHzjUrhnN6uq3LxrISeEeghKgb3v9IlJM_0J4Ec8rwImGnb88-R7JwCqi9IGQw4g9ia9QxO6SSAhhruYTGbZ5AUc2sVlCeTQhFMW6mjMWvRov7ubmIa5E1lpsAE9mmqdW4EC2tosMIPmrGEe8LF7rIanHmTCn2fidI0qHxnduMWBeAuyK9GZ_kst1dkc5yVWAqFijWst6qHy_TfNyyvy9C5KRq5nSdTwmg6xrSOfQIio49t9hWwFzuM9M5PVdbmh61fz-gjEc1HK4PYkjXNj8sLwhWn7BjH9wzLokJI4N56EnPKHCcAagN1ASOmMHe9c9vLBrihNWpLO1twCSp7sVlJS-J19mWmZcIBpHM3P3PZfZnBmgmlXDo48aU57wdYftgZZ-EHJ4yfhKHiKqRz5TXWsLqzBFc_iDcm_QsHRKCd4goqjyCTIGymCx3QVw19VfWmQYxAktsgy7z4axRbRSx-ocDT3UX0_qYaNGK0DwsIcq6_SYqu0I7BrlkQ4x7YY).

I try the [Offset](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/row#Offsetting-columns) too but I can set the padding between Button.

Comment: If your concern is that string lengthy may be grater then button width then apply css  `.truncate {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}` and this not what you are looking for then let's fix it call me on skype: syed_haroon

Comment: @Syed I know but I dont want truncate the string, the string must full to user.

Comment: If you comfortable in talking english then call me on skype, let's fix it.